# using functions within tables in word 2010

Tags: ms-word, formulas

I've created an invoice within word, i have a table with 2 columns with the following headings "description" "Cost" at the bottom of the table i have 3 rows "Subtotal" "VAT" and "Total" the headings sit under the description column and the values for these sit under the cost column.

```
Description           cost
example 1             £ 5.00
example 2             £ 15.99


Subtotal              £      
VAT                   £
Total                 £
```

i have used the following formula for the 'subtotal' cell

```
=sum(ABOVE)
```

this works fine

i then tried `=B3/100*20` for the formula for the VAT cell but this returned 0. so i did `=ABOVE/100*20` this worked but rounded the value up.

my issue is how do i firstly stop the rounding of numbers within formulas in word, and my second issue is i cant get the 'Total' to work. word does not like `=B3+B4` or did not like this`=SUM(B3:B4)`

any help on this would be appreciated. i didn't realise creating an invoice within word would be so time consuming!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROUND` function and specify the number of digits you would like to round to. In your case you should be able to calculate the VAT using the following formula:

```
=ROUND(SUM(ABOVE)/100*20;4)
```

A more detailed documentation is available here:

> [**Use a formula in a Word or Outlook table**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-in-a-Word-or-Outlook-table-cbd0596e-ea8a-485e-a35d-b2cb2c4f3e27)

Comment: im not sure what is going on i have tried everything and get '=ROUND(SUM(ABOVE)/100*20;4)'                                                      '!Syntax Error, ;'

Comment: @sql2015: It might be that you need to use a comma instead of a semicolon as a separator character.

Comment: it must be my version of word. I've tried commas and semi colons. read numerous websites and still cant get it to work

Comment: Done it - if i write the formula under "Toggle field codes" rather than in the 'wizard' it works fine!